# PHP Object as XML Document

Tags: php, xml, xml-serialization

What is the best way to take a given PHP object and serialize it as XML? I am looking at simple_xml and I have used it to parse XML into objects, but it isn't clear to me how it works the other way around.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

take a look at PEAR's [XML_Serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer) package. I've used it with pretty good results. You can feed it arrays, objects etc and it will turn them into XML. It also has a bunch of options like picking the name of the root node etc.

Should do the trick

Comment: I'm trying to use this package today (4 years after this response) on php 5.3.13 and I'm getting Strict Standards errors on XML_Serializer and its dependencies. Know of any other alternatives?

Comment: Warning, the library has horrible dependencies!

Answer (score 54):

I'd agree with using PEAR's XML_Serializer, but if you want something simple that supports objects/arrays that have properties nested, you can use this.

```
class XMLSerializer {

    // functions adopted from http://www.sean-barton.co.uk/2009/03/turning-an-array-or-object-into-xml-using-php/

    public static function generateValidXmlFromObj(stdClass $obj, $node_block='nodes', $node_name='node') {
        $arr = get_object_vars($obj);
        return self::generateValidXmlFromArray($arr, $node_block, $node_name);
    }

    public static function generateValidXmlFromArray($array, $node_block='nodes', $node_name='node') {
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';

        $xml .= '<' . $node_block . '>';
        $xml .= self::generateXmlFromArray($array, $node_name);
        $xml .= '</' . $node_block . '>';

        return $xml;
    }

    private static function generateXmlFromArray($array, $node_name) {
        $xml = '';

        if (is_array($array) || is_object($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
                if (is_numeric($key)) {
                    $key = $node_name;
                }

                $xml .= '<' . $key . '>' . self::generateXmlFromArray($value, $node_name) . '</' . $key . '>';
            }
        } else {
            $xml = htmlspecialchars($array, ENT_QUOTES);
        }

        return $xml;
    }

}
```

Comment: nice, works great for me. especially if you don't want any dependencies from PEAR.

Comment: Can someone give an example usage of this please? Really struggling.

Comment: @MattBoyle, I used json_decode to get the simpleXML as an object. Try this with your object. `$xml_generater = new XMLSerializer;
 $std_class = json_decode(json_encode($object));
 $xml = $xml_generater->generateValidXmlFromObj($std_class); `

Comment: very useful, thanks. But it will be insufficient if you need to generate XML with multiple items in the same depth, because array keys cannot be identical.

Comment: @Philfreo, thanks for the solution, in Laravel 5.5 it gives me error object not instance of stdClass. till I removed the stdClass from the generateValidXmlFromObj method then it worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

not quite an answer to the original question, but the way i solved my problem with this was by declaring my object as:

```
$root = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Activities/>';
$object = new simpleXMLElement($root);
```

as opposed to:

```
$object = new stdClass;
```

before i started adding any values!

Comment: When you are done just call the `asXML()` function to get the generated XML, or for the inner xml use children()->asXml() awsome!

Answer (score 7):

Use a dom function to do it:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php

Import the SimpleXML object and then save. The above link contains an example. :)

In a nutshell:

```
<?php
$array = array('hello' => 'world', 'good' => 'morning');

$xml = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><foo />");
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
  $xml->addChild($k, $v);
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, I'm pretty sure he wants to do something like convert array("foo" => "bar") into "<xml><foo>bar</foo></xml>" (not exactly, but you get the idea)

Comment: You can populate a simplexml object?

Comment: But he didn't ask how to convert simplexml objects into xml, he wanted plain XML objects. Unless I misunderstood, I didn't see an easy way to turn an arbitrary PHP data structure (objects, arrays, strings etc) into a simplexml object (and thus into an XML string)

Comment: still doesn't answer it. you're giving an array, not an object. and even if you used `get_object_vars` first it wouldn't work recursively.

Comment: only 1 level convertion

Answer (score 3):

take a look at my version

```
    class XMLSerializer {

    /**
     * 
     * The most advanced method of serialization.
     * 
     * @param mixed $obj => can be an objectm, an array or string. may contain unlimited number of subobjects and subarrays
     * @param string $wrapper => main wrapper for the xml
     * @param array (key=>value) $replacements => an array with variable and object name replacements
     * @param boolean $add_header => whether to add header to the xml string
     * @param array (key=>value) $header_params => array with additional xml tag params
     * @param string $node_name => tag name in case of numeric array key
     */
    public static function generateValidXmlFromMixiedObj($obj, $wrapper = null, $replacements=array(), $add_header = true, $header_params=array(), $node_name = 'node') 
    {
        $xml = '';
        if($add_header)
            $xml .= self::generateHeader($header_params);
        if($wrapper!=null) $xml .= '<' . $wrapper . '>';
        if(is_object($obj))
        {
            $node_block = strtolower(get_class($obj));
            if(isset($replacements[$node_block])) $node_block = $replacements[$node_block];
            $xml .= '<' . $node_block . '>';
            $vars = get_object_vars($obj);
            if(!empty($vars))
            {
                foreach($vars as $var_id => $var)
                {
                    if(isset($replacements[$var_id])) $var_id = $replacements[$var_id];
                    $xml .= '<' . $var_id . '>';
                    $xml .= self::generateValidXmlFromMixiedObj($var, null, $replacements,  false, null, $node_name);
                    $xml .= '</' . $var_id . '>';
                }
            }
            $xml .= '</' . $node_block . '>';
        }
        else if(is_array($obj))
        {
            foreach($obj as $var_id => $var)
            {
                if(!is_object($var))
                {
                    if (is_numeric($var_id)) 
                        $var_id = $node_name;
                    if(isset($replacements[$var_id])) $var_id = $replacements[$var_id]; 
                    $xml .= '<' . $var_id . '>';    
                }   
                $xml .= self::generateValidXmlFromMixiedObj($var, null, $replacements,  false, null, $node_name);
                if(!is_object($var))
                    $xml .= '</' . $var_id . '>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $xml .= htmlspecialchars($obj, ENT_QUOTES);
        }

        if($wrapper!=null) $xml .= '</' . $wrapper . '>';

        return $xml;
    }   

    /**
     * 
     * xml header generator
     * @param array $params
     */
    public static function generateHeader($params = array())
    {
        $basic_params = array('version' => '1.0', 'encoding' => 'UTF-8');
        if(!empty($params))
            $basic_params = array_merge($basic_params,$params);

        $header = '<?xml';
        foreach($basic_params as $k=>$v)
        {
            $header .= ' '.$k.'='.$v;
        }
        $header .= ' ?>';
        return $header;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you compare and contrast this to the options provided earlier?

Comment: Great solution!!! It works fine with deep arrays of objetcs and arrays. Thank you.

Comment: Great solution. Little remarks ... In the case of classes defined with multi-level namespaces, you may get into trouble. In the case of accented "properties/values", you may also get in trouble.

Comment: When values are turned into tag names and when such values contain invalid characters, they also must be taken into account

Answer (score 2):

use WDDX:
 http://uk.php.net/manual/en/wddx.examples.php

(if this extension is installed)

it's dedicated to that:

http://www.openwddx.org/

Comment: "www.openwddx.org
is for sale."

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code used for serializing PHP objects to XML "understandable" by Microsoft .NET XmlSerializer.Deserialize

```
class XMLSerializer {

    /**
     * Get object class name without namespace
     * @param object $object Object to get class name from
     * @return string Class name without namespace
     */
    private static function GetClassNameWithoutNamespace($object) {
        $class_name = get_class($object);
        return end(explode('\\', $class_name));
    }

    /**
     * Converts object to XML compatible with .NET XmlSerializer.Deserialize 
     * @param type $object Object to serialize
     * @param type $root_node Root node name (if null, objects class name is used)
     * @return string XML string
     */
    public static function Serialize($object, $root_node = null) {
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
        if (!$root_node) {
            $root_node = self::GetClassNameWithoutNamespace($object);
        }
        $xml .= '<' . $root_node . ' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">';
        $xml .= self::SerializeNode($object);
        $xml .= '</' . $root_node . '>';
        return $xml;
    }

    /**
     * Create XML node from object property
     * @param mixed $node Object property
     * @param string $parent_node_name Parent node name
     * @param bool $is_array_item Is this node an item of an array?
     * @return string XML node as string
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static function SerializeNode($node, $parent_node_name = false, $is_array_item = false) {
        $xml = '';
        if (is_object($node)) {
            $vars = get_object_vars($node);
        } else if (is_array($node)) {
            $vars = $node;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Coś poszło nie tak');
        }

        foreach ($vars as $k => $v) {
            if (is_object($v)) {
                $node_name = ($parent_node_name ? $parent_node_name : self::GetClassNameWithoutNamespace($v));
                if (!$is_array_item) {
                    $node_name = $k;
                }
                $xml .= '<' . $node_name . '>';
                $xml .= self::SerializeNode($v);
                $xml .= '</' . $node_name . '>';
            } else if (is_array($v)) {
                $xml .= '<' . $k . '>';
                if (count($v) > 0) {
                    if (is_object(reset($v))) {
                        $xml .= self::SerializeNode($v, self::GetClassNameWithoutNamespace(reset($v)), true);
                    } else {
                        $xml .= self::SerializeNode($v, gettype(reset($v)), true);
                    }
                } else {
                    $xml .= self::SerializeNode($v, false, true);
                }
                $xml .= '</' . $k . '>';
            } else {
                $node_name = ($parent_node_name ? $parent_node_name : $k);
                if ($v === null) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $xml .= '<' . $node_name . '>';
                    if (is_bool($v)) {
                        $xml .= $v ? 'true' : 'false';
                    } else {
                        $xml .= htmlspecialchars($v, ENT_QUOTES);
                    }
                    $xml .= '</' . $node_name . '>';
                }
            }
        }
        return $xml;
    }
}
```

example:

```
class GetProductsCommandResult {
    public $description;
    public $Errors;
}

class Error {
    public $id;
    public $error;
}

$obj = new GetProductsCommandResult();
$obj->description = "Teścik";
$obj->Errors = array();
$obj->Errors[0] = new Error();
$obj->Errors[0]->id = 666;
$obj->Errors[0]->error = "Sth";
$obj->Errors[1] = new Error();
$obj->Errors[1]->id = 666;
$obj->Errors[1]->error = null;


$xml = XMLSerializer::Serialize($obj);
```

results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetProductsCommandResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <description>Teścik</description>
   <Errors>
      <Error>
         <id>666</id>
         <error>Sth</error>
      </Error>
      <Error>
         <id>666</id>
      </Error>
   </Errors>
</GetProductsCommandResult>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but recently I had to generate complex XML structures.

My approach contains advanced OOP principles. The idea is to serialize the parent object who contains multiple children and subchildren.

Nodes get names from the class names but you can override the class name with the first parameter when creating an object for serialization.

You can create: a Simple node, without child nodes, EntityList and ArrayList. EntityList is a list of objects of the same class, but an ArrayList may have different objects.

Each object has to extend the abstract class *SerializeXmlAbstract* in order to match first input parameter in class: Object2xml,  method `serialize($object, $name = NULL, $prefix = FALSE)`.

By default, if you don't provide the second parameter, the root XML node will have  the class name of the given object. The third parameter indicates if root node name has a prefix or not. Prefix is hardcoded as a private property in Export2xml class.

```
interface SerializeXml {

    public function hasAttributes();

    public function getAttributes();

    public function setAttributes($attribs = array());

    public function getNameOwerriden();

    public function isNameOwerriden();
}

abstract class SerializeXmlAbstract implements SerializeXml {

    protected $attributes;
    protected $nameOwerriden;

    function __construct($name = NULL) {
        $this->nameOwerriden = $name;
    }

    public function getAttributes() {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

    public function getNameOwerriden() {
        return $this->nameOwerriden;
    }

    public function setAttributes($attribs = array()) {
        $this->attributes = $attribs;
    }

    public function hasAttributes() {
        return (is_array($this->attributes) && count($this->attributes) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    public function isNameOwerriden() {
        return $this->nameOwerriden != NULL ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

}

abstract class Entity_list extends SplObjectStorage {

    protected $_listItemType;

    public function __construct($type) {
        $this->setListItemType($type);
    }

    private function setListItemType($param) {
        $this->_listItemType = $param;
    }

    public function detach($object) {
        if ($object instanceOf $this->_listItemType) {
            parent::detach($object);
        }
    }

    public function attach($object, $data = null) {
        if ($object instanceOf $this->_listItemType) {
            parent::attach($object, $data);
        }
    }

}

abstract class Array_list extends SerializeXmlAbstract {

    protected $_listItemType;
    protected $_items;

    public function __construct() {
        //$this->setListItemType($type);
        $this->_items = new SplObjectStorage();
    }

    protected function setListItemType($param) {
        $this->_listItemType = $param;
    }

    public function getArray() {
        $return = array();
        $this->_items->rewind();
        while ($this->_items->valid()) {
            $return[] = $this->_items->current();
            $this->_items->next();
        }
        // print_r($return);
        return $return;
    }

    public function detach($object) {
        if ($object instanceOf $this->_listItemType) {
            if (in_array($this->_items->contains($object))) {
                $this->_items->detach($object);
            }
        }
    }

    public function attachItem($ob) {
        $this->_items->attach($ob);
    }

}

class Object2xml {

    public $rootPrefix = "ernm";
    private $addPrefix;
    public $xml;

    public function serialize($object, $name = NULL, $prefix = FALSE) {
        if ($object instanceof SerializeXml) {
            $this->xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
            $this->xml->appendChild($this->object2xml($object, $name, TRUE));
            $this->xml->formatOutput = true;
            echo $this->xml->saveXML();
        } else {
            die("Not implement SerializeXml interface");
        }
    }

    protected function object2xml(SerializeXmlAbstract $object, $nodeName = NULL, $prefix = null) {
        $single = property_exists(get_class($object), "value");
        $nName = $nodeName != NULL ? $nodeName : get_class($object);

        if ($prefix) {
            $nName = $this->rootPrefix . ":" . $nName;
        }
        if ($single) {
            $ref = $this->xml->createElement($nName);
        } elseif (is_object($object)) {
            if ($object->isNameOwerriden()) {
                $nodeName = $object->getNameOwerriden();
            }
            $ref = $this->xml->createElement($nName);
            if ($object->hasAttributes()) {
                foreach ($object->getAttributes() as $key => $value) {
                    $ref->setAttribute($key, $value);
                }
            }
            foreach (get_object_vars($object) as $n => $prop) {
                switch (gettype($prop)) {
                    case "object":
                        if ($prop instanceof SplObjectStorage) {
                            $ref->appendChild($this->handleList($n, $prop));
                        } elseif ($prop instanceof Array_list) {
                            $node = $this->object2xml($prop);
                            foreach ($object->ResourceGroup->getArray() as $key => $value) {
                                $node->appendChild($this->object2xml($value));
                            }
                            $ref->appendChild($node);
                        } else {
                            $ref->appendChild($this->object2xml($prop));
                        }
                        break;
                    default :
                        if ($prop != null) {
                            $ref->appendChild($this->xml->createElement($n, $prop));
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        } elseif (is_array($object)) {
            foreach ($object as $value) {
                $ref->appendChild($this->object2xml($value));
            }
        }
        return $ref;
    }

    private function handleList($name, SplObjectStorage $param, $nodeName = NULL) {
        $lst = $this->xml->createElement($nodeName == NULL ? $name : $nodeName);
        $param->rewind();
        while ($param->valid()) {
            if ($param->current() != null) {
                $lst->appendChild($this->object2xml($param->current()));
            }
            $param->next();
        }
        return $lst;
    }
}
```

This is code you need to be able to get valid xml from objects. Next sample produces this xml:

```
<InsertMessage priority="high">
  <NodeSimpleValue firstAttrib="first" secondAttrib="second">simple value</NodeSimpleValue>
  <Arrarita>
    <Title>PHP OOP is great</Title>
    <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
    <Child>
      <FirstChild>Jimmy</FirstChild>
    </Child>
    <Child2>
      <FirstChild>bird</FirstChild>
    </Child2>
  </Arrarita>
  <ThirdChild>
    <NodeWithChilds>
      <FirstChild>John</FirstChild>
      <ThirdChild>James</ThirdChild>
    </NodeWithChilds>
    <NodeWithChilds>
      <FirstChild>DomDocument</FirstChild>
      <SecondChild>SplObjectStorage</SecondChild>
    </NodeWithChilds>
  </ThirdChild>
</InsertMessage>
```

Classes needed for this xml are:

```
class NodeWithArrayList extends Array_list {

    public $Title;
    public $SequenceNumber;

    public function __construct($name = NULL) {
        echo $name;
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

}

class EntityListNode extends Entity_list {

    public function __construct($name = NULL) {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

}

class NodeWithChilds extends SerializeXmlAbstract {

    public $FirstChild;
    public $SecondChild;
    public $ThirdChild;

    public function __construct($name = NULL) {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

}

class NodeSimpleValue extends SerializeXmlAbstract {

    protected $value;

    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function __construct($name = NULL) {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }
}
```

And finally code that instantiate objects is:

```
$firstChild = new NodeSimpleValue("firstChild");
$firstChild->setValue( "simple value" );
$firstChild->setAttributes(array("firstAttrib" => "first", "secondAttrib" => "second"));

$secondChild = new NodeWithArrayList("Arrarita");       
$secondChild->Title = "PHP OOP is great";
$secondChild->SequenceNumber = 1;   


$firstListItem = new NodeWithChilds();
$firstListItem->FirstChild = "John";
$firstListItem->ThirdChild = "James";

$firstArrayItem = new NodeWithChilds("Child");
$firstArrayItem->FirstChild = "Jimmy";

$SecondArrayItem = new NodeWithChilds("Child2");   
$SecondArrayItem->FirstChild = "bird";

$secondListItem = new NodeWithChilds();
$secondListItem->FirstChild = "DomDocument";
$secondListItem->SecondChild = "SplObjectStorage";


$secondChild->attachItem($firstArrayItem);
$secondChild->attachItem($SecondArrayItem);

$list = new EntityListNode("NodeWithChilds");
$list->attach($firstListItem);
$list->attach($secondListItem);



$message = New NodeWithChilds("InsertMessage");
$message->setAttributes(array("priority" => "high"));
$message->FirstChild = $firstChild;
$message->SecondChild = $secondChild;
$message->ThirdChild = $list;


$object2xml = new Object2xml();
$object2xml->serialize($message, "xml", TRUE);
```

Hope it will help someone.

Cheers,
Siniša

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive method, like this:

```
private function ReadProperty($xmlElement, $object) {
    foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != null) {
            if (is_object($value)) {
                $element = $this->xml->createElement($key);
                $this->ReadProperty($element, $value);
                $xmlElement->AppendChild($element);
            } elseif (is_array($value)) {
                $this->ReadProperty($xmlElement, $value);
            } else {
                $this->AddAttribute($xmlElement, $key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the complete example:
http://www.tyrodeveloper.com/2018/09/convertir-clase-en-xml-con-php.html

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a class available via git that resolves this problem:

https://github.com/zappz88/XMLSerializer

Here is the class structure, and keep in mind that you will need to define the root properly for format proper xml:

```
class XMLSerializer {
    private $OpenTag = "<";
    private $CloseTag = ">";
    private $BackSlash = "/";
    public $Root = "root";

    public function __construct() {
    }

    private function Array_To_XML($array, $arrayElementName = "element_", $xmlString = "")
    {
        if($xmlString === "")
        {
            $xmlString = "{$this->OpenTag}{$this->Root}{$this->CloseTag}";
        }
        $startTag = "{$this->OpenTag}{$arrayElementName}{$this->CloseTag}";
        $xmlString .= $startTag;
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            if(gettype($value) === "string" || gettype($value) === "boolean" || gettype($value) === "integer" || gettype($value) === "double" || gettype($value) === "float")
            {
                $elementStartTag = "{$this->OpenTag}{$arrayElementName}_{$key}{$this->CloseTag}";
                $elementEndTag = "{$this->OpenTag}{$this->BackSlash}{$arrayElementName}_{$key}{$this->CloseTag}";
                $xmlString .= "{$elementStartTag}{$value}{$elementEndTag}";
                continue;
            }
            else if(gettype($value) === "array")
            {
                $xmlString = $this->Array_To_XML($value, $arrayElementName, $xmlString);
                continue;
            }
            else if(gettype($value) === "object")
            {
                $xmlString = $this->Object_To_XML($value, $xmlString);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {                
                continue;
            }
        }
        $endTag = "{$this->OpenTag}{$this->BackSlash}{$arrayElementName}{$this->CloseTag}";
        $xmlString .= $endTag;
        return $xmlString;
    }

    private function Object_To_XML($objElement, $xmlString = "")
    {
        if($xmlString === "")
        {
            $xmlString = "{$this->OpenTag}{$this->Root}{$this->CloseTag}";
        }
        foreach($objElement as $key => $value){
            if(gettype($value) !== "array" && gettype($value) !== "object")
            {
                $startTag = "{$this->OpenTag}{$key}{$this->CloseTag}";
                $endTag = "{$this->OpenTag}{$this->BackSlash}{$key}{$this->CloseTag}";
                $xmlString .= "{$startTag}{$value}{$endTag}";
                continue;
            }
            else if(gettype($value) === "array")
            {
                $xmlString = $this->Array_To_XML($value, $key, $xmlString);
                continue;
            }
            else if(gettype($value) === "object")
            {
                $xmlString = $this->Object_To_XML($value, $xmlString);
                continue;
            }
            else
            { 
                continue;
            }
        }
        return $xmlString;
    }

    public function Serialize_Object($element, $xmlString = "")
    {
        $endTag = "{$this->OpenTag}{$this->BackSlash}{$this->Root}{$this->CloseTag}";
        return "{$this->Object_To_XML($element, $xmlString)}{$endTag}";
    }

    public function Serialize_Array($element, $xmlString = "")
    {
        $endTag = "{$this->OpenTag}{$this->BackSlash}{$this->Root}{$this->CloseTag}";
        return "{$this->Array_To_XML($element, $xmlString)}{$endTag}";
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and this format is recognizable and parasable by PHP's xmlsimpleloadobject function.

Answer (score -1):

While I agree with @philfreo and his reasoning that you shouldn't be dependant on PEAR, his solution is still not quite there.  There are potential issues when the key could be a string that contains any of the following characters:

- <
- >
- \s (space)
- "
- '

Any of these will throw off the format, as XML uses these characters in its grammar.  So, without further ado, here is a simple solution to that very possible occurrence:

```
function xml_encode( $var, $indent = false, $i = 0 ) {
    $version = "1.0";
    if ( !$i ) {
        $data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' . ( $indent ? "\r\n" : '' )
                . '<root vartype="' . gettype( $var ) . '" xml_encode_version="'. $version . '">' . ( $indent ? "\r\n" : '' );
    }
    else {
        $data = '';
    }

    foreach ( $var as $k => $v ) {
        $data .= ( $indent ? str_repeat( "\t", $i ) : '' ) . '<var vartype="' .gettype( $v ) . '" varname="' . htmlentities( $k ) . '"';

        if($v == "") {
            $data .= ' />';
        }
        else {
            $data .= '>';
            if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
                $data .= ( $indent ? "\r\n" : '' ) . xml_encode( $v, $indent, $verbose, ($i + 1) ) . ( $indent ? str_repeat("\t", $i) : '' );
            }
            else if( is_object( $v ) ) {
                $data .= ( $indent ? "\r\n" : '' ) . xml_encode( json_decode( json_encode( $v ), true ), $indent, $verbose, ($i + 1)) . ($indent ? str_repeat("\t", $i) : '');
            }
            else {
                $data .= htmlentities( $v );
            }

            $data .= '</var>';
        }

        $data .= ($indent ? "\r\n" : '');
    }

    if ( !$i ) {
        $data .= '</root>';
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Here is a sample usage:

```
// sample object
$tests = Array(
    "stringitem" => "stringvalue",
    "integeritem" => 1,
    "floatitem" => 1.00,
    "arrayitems" =>  Array("arrayvalue1", "arrayvalue2"),
    "hashitems" => Array( "hashkey1" => "hashkey1value", "hashkey2" => "hashkey2value" ),
    "literalnull" => null,
    "literalbool" => json_decode( json_encode( 1 ) )
);
// add an objectified version of itself as a child
$tests['objectitem'] = json_decode( json_encode( $tests ), false);

// convert and output
echo xml_encode( $tests );

/*
// output:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root vartype="array" xml_encode_version="1.0">
<var vartype="integer" varname="integeritem">1</var>
<var vartype="string" varname="stringitem">stringvalue</var>
<var vartype="double" varname="floatitem">1</var>
<var vartype="array" varname="arrayitems">
    <var vartype="string" varname="0">arrayvalue1</var>
    <var vartype="string" varname="1">arrayvalue2</var>
</var>
<var vartype="array" varname="hashitems">
    <var vartype="string" varname="hashkey1">hashkey1value</var>
    <var vartype="string" varname="hashkey2">hashkey2value</var>
</var>
<var vartype="NULL" varname="literalnull" />
<var vartype="integer" varname="literalbool">1</var>
<var vartype="object" varname="objectitem">
    <var vartype="string" varname="stringitem">stringvalue</var>
    <var vartype="integer" varname="integeritem">1</var>
    <var vartype="integer" varname="floatitem">1</var>
    <var vartype="array" varname="arrayitems">
        <var vartype="string" varname="0">arrayvalue1</var>
        <var vartype="string" varname="1">arrayvalue2</var>
    </var>
    <var vartype="array" varname="hashitems">
        <var vartype="string" varname="hashkey1">hashkey1value</var>
        <var vartype="string" varname="hashkey2">hashkey2value</var>
    </var>
    <var vartype="NULL" varname="literalnull" />
    <var vartype="integer" varname="literalbool">1</var>
</var>
</root>

*/
```

Notice that the key names are stored in the varname attribute (html encoded), and even the type is stored, so symmetric de-serialization is possible.  There is only one issue with this: it will not serialize classes, only the instantiated object, which will not include the class methods.  This is only functional for passing "data" back and forth.

I hope this helps someone, even though this was answered long ago.

Answer (score -4):

Well, while a little dirty, you could always run a loop on the object's properties...

```
$_xml = '';
foreach($obj as $key => $val){
  $_xml .= '<' . $key . '>' . $val . '</' . $key . ">\n";
}
```

Using fopen/fwrite/fclose you could generate an XML doc with the `$_xml` variable as content. It's ugly, but it would work.

Comment: Got a slight syntax error.  No concatenation after the second $key.

Comment: works, but if you need to handle objects more than 1 level deep try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137021/php-object-as-xml-document/2194774#2194774

Comment: Are you kidding me?