# PHP: echo a value from simplexmloelement object

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

This is my code:

```
$xml2  = (array) simplexml_load_string($xml_file);
```

Using print_r this is my array:

```
 Array
(
  [program] => Array
        (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [date] => asgasg sgasgasg
            [start_time] => asdg asg
            [leadtext] => as asdgsagsdgasgasgd
            [name] => as gsadgasg
            [bline] => sag asdg
            [synopsis] => asg asga sdg
            [url] => asg sdgasgasg
        )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [date] => sgasgasg1
            [start_time] => asg1
            [leadtext] => as1
            [name] => gsadgasg1
            [bline] => asdg1
            [synopsis] => sdg1
            [url] =>sdgasgasg1
        )

        )
)
```

how can I do a echo to get the contents of [date] from the 2nd SimpleXMLElement (which is **sgasgasg1** in the above example)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object).

Comment: Thats using the OOP way, I am doing it procedural. I did find that when searching though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
echo $xml2['program'][1]->date;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
foreach($xml2['program'] as $key=>$value) {

   echo $value->date;

}
```

As you told in your comment only

```
echo $xml2['program'][1]->date;
```

Comment: No, I only want to get that specific value once, for example:  "The date is".$date_here