# Retrieve array value

Tags: php, arrays

Any idea about how I can retrieve email1@some.com, email2@some.com, email3@some.com, email4@some.com and email5@some.com from this array using PHP?

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => email1@some.com
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => email2@some.com
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => email3@some.com
        )

    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => email4@some.com
        )

    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => email5@some.com
        )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: What programming language is this for?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Store it in another array? Print it to screen? As text or HTML?

Comment: @AbeMiessler I am using PHP.

Comment: @DiMono The idea is to retrieve only the emails

Comment: I've added an answer below for how to get to the emails; you can do whatever you want with them from there.

Comment: As this looks like it was produced by SimpleXML, wouldn't it be more logical just to use SimpleXML to access the data properly instead of yanking them out like this?  It might be a good thing to add the code that led to this array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $email = $item[0];
    // Do something with $email
}
?>
```

Comment: This actually showed me how to solve the issue. You failed to specify that I need to cast the simpleXML Object to a string. Thanks by the way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object