# Retrieved value from xml php?

Tags: php

I need your help guys,
I have this issue:
When I use the `bigbluebutton api` for retrieve the meetings from the server I received this result:

```
Array
( 
    [returncode] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SUCCESS )
    [messageKey] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
    [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
     [meetingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1111)
     [meetingName] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Test MeetingName ) 
     [createTime] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1402148945933 )
     [attendeePw] =>       SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => passw)
     [moderatorPw] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => passw) 
     [hasBeenForciblyEnded] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => false )
     [running] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => false ) 
     )
)
```

Where the second array will be populated by the meetings. Now there is one meeting so u see only one element.
I don't need help with cycle for or foreach but I need your help for retrieve the meetingid or meetingname or attendepw.

i found this on stackoverflow :[Get value from SimpleXMLElement Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-)`simplexmlelement-object`
and the solution was: `$value = (string) $xml->code[0]->lat;`

But I think this is not the solution for me.
I tried this code:

`$array=$result['message'];
$id=$array['meetingId'];`

But now I can't retrieved the id from this $id.
Sorry for my English, any help will be appreciated

Comment: `But I think this is not the solution for me.` Have you tried it? You got errors?

Comment: I tried it.but no work..i don't know how can i formulate that code..i don't have an array of simplexml..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `meetingId SimpleXMLElement Object`

```
$meetingIdEl = $result[0]['meetingId'];
```

To get the value of meetingIdEl

```
$mettingId = $meetingIdEl->__toString(); // or (string)$meetingIdEl;
echo $meetingId; // 1111
```

[**SimpleXMLElement Documentation**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)

Comment: what can i say??do u wanna marry me?