# In PHP how do you get the simple text of an XML attribute only XML?

Tags: php, xml, attributes, traversal

I have an XML that's coming back from an cURL post that's returning:

```
$output=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mtMessageRsp carrier="102" messageId="769f2e4f-56da-4865-988a-a9199c387a48"/>
```

I'm returning this as an XML via:

```
return simplexml_load_string($output);
```

$result is catching the return and it's coming back as:

```
$result = { 
  "@attributes" :  { 
    carrier : "102",
    messageId : "8d691cbe-d188-42b1-9041-387666d39c6a"
  }
```

How can I drill down to get the messageId as plane text?  When I use this:

```
$result['messageId']
```

I get:

```
{ 
  "0" : "bf629ae9-c86a-486a-bfb0-704e16448ddf"
}
```

But I just want:

```
bf629ae9-c86a-486a-bfb0-704e16448ddf
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the indicated post that 'hakre' flagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in another post:

```
$msgID = (string) $result['messageId'];
```

You have to cast simpleXML Object to a string. 
POST: [Get value from SimpleXMLElement Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object)

Comment: You can also find a nice introduction to Simplexml in the PHP manual here: [Basic SimpleXML usage](https://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)