# How to display a value from a SimpleXML object (the array notation is confusing me)

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml, zoho

I have a PHP file that uses cURL to retrieve some XML. I now want to retrieve a value from the XML but I cannot traverse to it as I am confused with the notation.

Here's my retrieved XML:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [uri] => /fruit/apple/xml/green/pipType
    )

[result] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [JobOpenings] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [row] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [no] => 1
                                    )
                                [FL] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 308343000000092052
                                        [1] => ZR_6_JOB
                                    )
                            )
                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [no] => 2
                                    )
                                [FL] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 308343000000091031
                                        [1] => ZR_5_JOB
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

I have this XML stored in a variable called $xml using:

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Any help for how I can select the ZR_5_JOB element please?

I have tried countless times, the last effort I had was:

```
print_r($xml->result->JobOpenings->row[0]->FL[0]);
```

Could anybody please help?

(I know I will then need to do some iteration, but I'll deal with that later!)

Comment: Firstly, $xml->result->JobOpenings->row[0]->FL[0] would reference item 0 in FL - "308343000000091031". You need to reference the right key (FL[1]) - additionally to get the value check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object

Comment: Well spotted thanks; I'm going daft from looking at code today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First loop the JobOpenings rows to get each row separately and then you can access the childrens of that element in an easy way.

```
foreach($xml->result->JobOpenings->row as $item) {
    echo $item->FL[0] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly Karl. I just added in a line-break after each returned value  ` . '<br>'` ... tks