# How to access array element SimpleXMLElement Object in php

Tags: php, xml, linkedin-api

I am trying to resolve this issue as I connected with linkedin and trying to access following xml object in php to print out and access just names.

XML output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object(
    [id] => MFNqBCcdLOLO
    [first-name] => James
    [last-name] => Bond
    [picture-url] => https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_ljsdflkdsjfkjflkds
)
```

and my php code to print above is:

```
    $response = $OBJ_linkedin->profile('~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url)');
    print_r($response);
    if($response['success'] === TRUE) {
       $response['data'] = new SimpleXMLElement($response['linkedin']);
       //insert data...to linkedin_userprofile table...
       $linkedin = new Linkedinprofile();
            
       echo "<pre>" . print_r($response['data'], TRUE) . "</pre>";
```

Now if someone will help:

`$response['data']` print the output now how I can access `$response['data'][first-name]` like that.

Comment: Please check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object

Comment: `$value = (string) $xml->first-name;`, and please try to change indexes value `-`to`_`

Comment: no not work, as it return me >>>>0 when i apply following code $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response['linkedin']);
        $value = (string) $xml->first-name;
        echo ">>>>".$value;

Comment: Hi anant, how to do this? - $value = (string) $xml->first-name;, and please try to change indexes value -to_ so, i wanted to make first-name to first_name but how?

Comment: `$value = (string) $xml->{'first-name'};`

Comment: Thank you anant & splash guys you are awesome