# Trouble extracting string from SimpleXMLElement in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to extract the string value from the SimpleXMLElement below (which has been returned from a SOAP endpoint) but I'm having no joy:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[476]
  public 'return' => string 'ff7ecc8af5ecaaba412c3b453c5f65f1' (length=32)
```

I have tried casting the entire object as a string, it just returns empty, I've tried treating 'return' as key, etc. This is such a simple task, can't believe it's got me stumped.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, somewhat hidden in the question, is that the element name is a reserved word, so you can't use the ordinary syntax:

```
$value = (string)$xml->return; # SYNTAX ERROR
```

The solution is to use braces and quotes around the name, which allows you to use reserved words or characters:

```
$value = (string)$xml->{'return'};
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding (string) in front of the variable.  For example:

```
echo (string)$xml->fieldname;
```

The SimpleXMLElement stuff is very object-oriented but as you can see from the debug output you shared, the string is in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Lorna. The problem is, I don't have a fieldname. I tried to use 'return' as a fieldname, but can't because it's a reserved word.

Comment: Ah, totally missed that the reserved word was causing the issue!  @IMSoP spotted it though, awesome.