# How to get the values from this array?

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, curl

How to get the values ​​from this array?

I need to wipe this array and get the values ​​of each one

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [ArrayOfClienteDetalhe] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ClienteDetalhe] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [IdCliente] => 10
                            [Sequencial] => 6055
                            [IdDetalhe] => 61
                            [NomeDetalhe] => T77ER C7 
                            [TipoDetalhe] => Cliente
                            [TipoFormato] => Inteiro
                            [TipoInclusao] => Sim
                            [TipoConsulta] => Sim
                            [TipoExclusao] => Nao
                            [TipoAlteracao] => Nao
                            [TipoValor] => ValorUnico
                            [Valor] => 2
                            [TpMensagem] => Nenhum
                        )
                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [IdCliente] => 10
                            [Sequencial] => 10
                            [IdDetalhe] => 1
                            [NomeDetalhe] => ID CLIENTE
                            [TipoDetalhe] => Cliente
                            [TipoFormato] => Texto
                            [TipoInclusao] => Sim
                            [TipoConsulta] => Sim
                            [TipoExclusao] => Nao
                            [TipoAlteracao] => Nao
                            [TipoValor] => ValorUnico
                            [Valor] => 00039523777706
                            [TpMensagem] => Nenhum
                        )
                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [IdCliente] => 10
                            [Sequencial] => 6054
                            [IdDetalhe] => 33
                            [NomeDetalhe] => NA_NATIONALITY
                            [TipoDetalhe] => Cliente
                            [TipoFormato] => Texto
                            [TipoInclusao] => Sim
                            [TipoConsulta] => Sim
                            [TipoExclusao] => Nao
                            [TipoAlteracao] => Nao
                            [TipoValor] => ValorUnico
                            [Valor] => BRA
                            [TpMensagem] => Nenhum
                        )
                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [IdCliente] => 10
                            [Sequencial] => 15552076
                            [IdDetalhe] => 8555
                            [NomeDetalhe] => NOV
                            [TipoDetalhe] => Cliente
                            [TipoFormato] => Texto
                            [TipoInclusao] => Sim
                            [TipoConsulta] => Sim
                            [TipoExclusao] => Nao
                            [TipoAlteracao] => Nao
                            [TipoValor] => ValorUnico
                            [Valor] => 2016117711
                            [TpMensagem] => Nenhum
                        )
                )
        )
```

Comment: show that `SimpleXMLElement` as raw xml string and expected result

Comment: See below as below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from SimpleXMLElement Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object)

Comment: Not working I saw this post

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultAux = html_entity_decode($result);
        $xmlobj = simplexml_load_string($resultAux) or die("Error: Cannot create object");      
        if($xmlobj === false){
            echo "Failed loading XML: ";
            foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
                echo "
", $error->message;
            }
        }else{
            print_r($xmlobj);
        }
```