# PHP Parsing of XML Response from API

Tags: php, xml, api, parsing, simplexml

I have an XML response that I'm trying to extract a single item from, here is the response:

```
<GetProductStockResponse>
  <GetProductStockResult>
    <ProductStock>
      <Product>
        <sku>AA-HF461</sku>
        <stock>23</stock>
      </Product>
    </ProductStock>
  </GetProductStockResult>
</GetProductStockResponse>
```

If I echo this to the screen is is displayed as:

```
AA-HF461 23
```

I tried using simplexml_load_string but it's not working, nothing comes out:

```
$res = $soapClient->GetProductStock($q_param);    
$clfResponse = $res->GetProductStockResult;
echo $clfResponse; // This works - see above

$xml = simplexml_load_string($clfResponse);
echo $xml; // This is empty         
echo $xml->stock; // This is empty
```

Am I making a schoolboy error?

Comment: Check your browser source page (CTRL+U in Chrome). You'll see the entire XML

Comment: echo $xml->asXml() is empty?

Comment: echo gettype($xml); returns object or string?

Comment: Ah, I see. Did you try $xml->ProductStock->Product->stock?

Comment: echo $xml->asXml() returns AA-HF461 23

Comment: echo gettype($xml); returns 'object'

Comment: Fyntasia - I tried $xml->ProductStock->Product->stock but this returns empty.

Comment: are you expecting something  like this ? https://eval.in/845574

Comment: If I look at the source I can see the XML data:

Comment: <ProductStock>
  <Product>
    <sku>AA-HF461</sku>
    <stock>23</stock>
  </Product>
</ProductStock>

Comment: @Waloob73 You want this to be displayed on browser `<ProductStock> <Product> <sku>AA-HF461</sku> <stock>23</stock> </Product> </ProductStock>`

Comment: Sahil Gulati - I just want the stock quantity as a number, not the SKU part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo $xml` will print the string value of the outer tag of your XML. Since the `GetProductStockResponse` doesn't have any text content, there is no output. If you want to dump the full XML as a string, use

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

`echo $xml->stock;` will also be empty, as the outer element does not contain a `<stock>` tag. If you want to drill down to it, you need to access it via each level of the document:

```
echo (int) $xml->GetProductStockResult->ProductStock->Product->stock; // 23
```

(The typecasts are important when dealing with SimpleXML elements, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object) for more details)

If you want to be able to access elements from any level of the document, you can use SimpleXML's `xpath` method, like this:

```
echo (int) $xml->xpath('//stock')[0]; // 23
```

This will print the first `<stock>` element from any level of the document, but in general it's a better idea to navigate the document according to its structure.

Finally, if you are testing this via a browser, be aware that XML elements will not render correctly unless you escape the output:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML());
```

Comment: iainn - the second option works perfectly - echo (int) $xml->xpath('//stock')[0];

Many thanks!