# how to remove SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml, laravel-5

How can i remove " SimpleXMLElement Object" from   the following array

Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => IVA ) ) Array ( [0] => 
      SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 566.90 ) )

i have this code in my Controller

```
 $count=0;
foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Impuestos//cfdi:Traslados//cfdi:Traslado') as $nodo){                                                                        




        $importes[] = $nodo['importe'];
        $impuestos[] = $nodo['impuesto'];
        $count++;


            }

                    $num_elementos[]=$count;


    $limite_prueba=count($num_elementos);

    $corte = 0;


    for ($x=0;$x<$limite_prueba;$x++){

        $salida = array_slice($importes, $corte, $num_elementos[$x]);
        $salida_imp = array_slice($impuestos, $corte, $num_elementos[$x]);

        $resultado = array_unique($salida);
        $resultado2 = array_unique($salida_imp);



                print_r($resultado2);
                print_r($resultado);
            echo "<br>";


                $corte = $corte + $num_elementos[$x];



    }
```

Comment: I think this question is related to this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object

Comment: What do you mean by "delete"?

Comment: i want to show the array without "SimpleXMLElement Object"

Comment: `SimpleXMLElement`s can be stringified.