# Need help getting a value from a simplexml object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am looking to get the date of the simple xml object below. I have tried so many different ways to get it and could get it. Below is the the object when I used var_dump()  I am trying to get this value 2018-08-16T16:48:49Z

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(8) "datetime" } 
    [0]=> string(20) "2018-08-16T16:48:49Z" 
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can we see xml structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from SimpleXMLElement Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your variable is called `$obj` you should be able to get its value with

```
echo (string)$obj;
```

Some test code:

```
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><data type="datetime">2018-08-16T16:48:49Z</data>';
$obj = simplexml_load_string($str);
var_dump($obj);
echo (string)$obj;
```

Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["type"]=>string(8) "datetime" }
  [0]=>string(20) "2018-08-16T16:48:49Z"
}
2018-08-16T16:48:49Z
```