# Is there any class or library in PHP to parse and convert PHP Class structure with comments(PHPdoc) to XML?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is there any class or library in PHP to parse and convert PHP Class structure with comments(PHPdoc) to XML?
I Know about Reflection class. but i want standalone class to convert class (methods,properties,comments and access method) to XML form..

Comment: What do you mean by standalone class? And why is the Reflection API not good enough? What do you need this for? Can PHPDocumentor or Doxygen do what you are looking for? Please clarify the question.

Comment: refelection api is good but its not used for parsing comments block..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Object as XML Document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137021/php-object-as-xml-document)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any pre-existing classes but a combination of Reflection and DOM should enable you to roll your own.