# PHP - JSON to SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a bunch of PHP web services that construct JSON objects and deliver them using `json_encode`.

This works fine but I now have a requirement that the web services can also deliver in XML, depending on a given parameter.

I want to stay away from PEAR XML if possible, and hopefully find a simple solution that can be implemented with SimpleXML.

Can anyone give me any advice?

Thanks

Comment: yes, it can be implemented with SimpleXml. Please clarify what kind of advice are you looking for?

Comment: For converting your objects to XML see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137021/php-object-as-xml-document

Comment: See above - I want to stay away from PEAR XML if possible. I want to use SimpleXML. I just want to know if there is an easy function, as easy as json_encode for instance, that will convert JSON to XML.

Comment: @adam - I find myself with the same need to feed json to SimpleXML, and the same desire to avoid any PEAR dependencies...did you have any luck finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an associative array using `json_decode($json,true)` and try the following function to convert to xml.

```
function assocArrayToXML($root_element_name,$ar)
{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><{$root_element_name}></{$root_element_name}>");
    $f = function($f,$c,$a) {
            foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
                if(is_array($v)) {
                    $ch=$c->addChild($k);
                    $f($f,$ch,$v);
                } else {
                    $c->addChild($k,$v);
                }
            }
    };
    $f($f,$xml,$ar);
    return $xml->asXML();
} 

// usage
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo assocArrayToXML("root",$data);
```